# seen people pulling together

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "seen people pulling together" mean "witnessed people being united"?

> "We have **seen people pulling together** over the past year: food banks, community food projects, businesses, and creative local authorities. No one disputes the importance of this phenomenal response, but food aid is a sticking plaster"
> Source: The BMJ (British Medical Journal)

Comment: Yes, **working together to achieve a common purpose**, as you surmise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Pulling together* is working as a team (not necessarily a formal one) to get a job done - like sailors pulling on a rope. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-together